# annotation to filter results of a @OneToMany association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

I have parent/child relationship between two tables, and the corresponding mapping in my Java classes. The tables roughly look like that:

```
A (ref number, stuff varchar2(4000))
B (a_ref number, other number, foo varchar2(200))
```

and the Java code:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "REF")
    private int ref;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_REF", referencedName = "REF")
    private Set<B> bs;
}

@Entity
class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_REF")
    private int aRef;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OTHER")
    private int other;
}
```

This works fine, but I'd like to add a filter on the rows that I retrieve from the child table. The query that is generated looks like:

```
select a_ref, other, foo from B where a_ref = ?
```

And I'd like it to be:

```
select a_ref, other, foo from B where a_ref = ? and other = 123
```

The additional filter would be only a column name and a hard-coded value. Is there a way to do that using hibernate annotations?

I've looked at `@JoinFormula`, but with that I always have to reference a column name from the parent table (in the `name` attribute of the JoinFormula).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Curious, why not just pass it in as a parameter? `where a_ref = ? and other = ?`. The value passed in can be hardcoded if that is what you need to do (I would suggest using a configurable properties system though).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is not supported by JPA but if you are using hibernate as JPA provider then you can use annotation `@FilterDef` and `@Filter`.

> [Hibernate Core Reference Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters)
>
> Hibernate3 has the ability to pre-define filter criteria and attach
>   those filters at both a class level and a collection level. A filter
>   criteria allows you to define a restriction clause similar to the
>   existing "where" attribute available on the class and various
>   collection elements. These filter conditions, however, can be
>   parameterized. The application can then decide at runtime whether
>   certain filters should be enabled and what their parameter values
>   should be. Filters can be used like database views, but they are
>   parameterized inside the application.

**Exemple**

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "REF")
    private int ref;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_REF", referencedColumnName = "REF")   
    @Filter(name="test")
    private Set<B> bs;
}

@Entity
@FilterDef(name="test", defaultCondition="other = 123")
public class B implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_REF")
    private int aRef;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OTHER")
    private int other;
}

Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.enableFilter("test");
A a = entityManager.find(A.class, new Integer(0))
a.getb().size() //Only contains b that are equals to 123
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. It's a bit annoying though that you have to enable it dynamically (I will always enable it). I'll live with it!

Comment: There is no  upwrap method on entityManager :(

Comment: Sorry, it's only available since JPA 2.0. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)

Comment: maybe this is not correct, but from what I have read it seems to me that this is application filter, not addition to where condition, is it so?

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to use Hibernate's @Where: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-where

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_REF", referencedName = "REF")
    @Where(clause = "other = 123")
    private Set<B> bs;
```

Answer (score 2):

with JPA 1 you can use the provided solution but change unwrap to getDelegate to be like that

```
Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
```

and it's going to work.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question right, there is a way to do this with javax.persistence annotations (I used this on a ManyToOne myself, and tailored the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831357/how-to-replace-a-joincolumn-with-a-hardcoded-value/38657768#38657768)):

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_REF", referencedColumnName = "REF"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_TABLE_NAME.OTHER", referencedColumnName = "'123'")})
@OneToMany
private Set<B> bs;
```

Note the **single** quotes in the referencedColumnName, this is the value you are looking for.

More information [here](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_mapping_notes_nonstdjoins.html).