# How to retrieve the data based on the relationship in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, criteria, hibernate-criteria

am new to Hibernate.
  I have two tables named "User" and "Details". These two tables are mapped as " one-to-many ".
The mapping process is given as follow.

```
    @Entity
    public class User { 
    private int id;
    private Strng name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="user" )

    private Collection<Details> details;//= new ArrayList<Details>();
    ....getters and setters.....
   }
```

and Details class is

```
    @Entity
    public class Details{ 
    private int id;
    private Strng address;
    private String deleted;
    }
```

And this one to many relation works fine..

Now i want to retrieve the data from " details " table of particular record in " user " table with an additional condition ie, "deleted " field is equal to the string  "NO".

For this requirement hibernate, how can i achieve this one.

Filters or criteria or some one else ,, which one is the best way to solve my problem, with out break the relation.

I mean , with the help of relations we simple get all the data at single line of code, like " user_obj.getDetails()" .  In the same way we can simple get the data from the data base with extra conditions with less code.

Thank u to all,, in advance.......

Comment: yep, you can annotate your class using NamedQueries and NamedQuery, where you can write the query yourself, and then just execute it from where you need it - http://web.securityinnovation.com/appsec-weekly/blog/bid/69738/Use-Named-Queries-with-Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using [Hibernate filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

First define a filter on your child table i,e `Details`

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name="filterDeleted", defaultCondition="Deleted='NO'")
public class Details{
```

then you need to have `@Filter` annotation on parent table i,e `User`

```
    @Entity
    public class User { 
    private int id;
    private Strng name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="user" )
    @Filter(name="filterDeleted")
    private Collection<Details> details;//= new ArrayList<Details>();
    ....getters and setters.....
   }
```

and you need to enable the filter while fetching the content

```
session.enableFilter("filterDeleted");
session.load(...);
```

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919686/annotation-to-filter-results-of-a-onetomany-association) thread for more reference

But I would suggest you to **avoid filters** if the data is **too large**, cause I have experienced trouble using `@OnetoMany` with `@Filter` and later i had to fetch the child table separately using Criteria and attach them.