# Hibernate eager/lazy load with constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

```
ClassA {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "a_id")
 private long id;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "classA")
 private Set<ClassB> classBs;

}

ClassB {

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
 private ClassA classA;

 @JoinColumn(name = "size")
 private int size;

}
```

How can I add constraint to ClassA's classBs when eager/lazy load it?

For example, I only want to load ClassB where size > 10 into ClassA's Set classBs.

I know that I can order the Set by using annotation @OrderBy(value = "size ASC"), but can I add constraints other than Order?

Can I achieve it using Hibernate?

I am able to do it in Laravel(a PHP framework). Eager Load Constraints in http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Hibernate `Filters`:
[Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)
[Sample](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/)
There is one thing that you should notice and that is the filters are not applied to the entity permanently and you need to enable them whenever you would like to use them:

```
session.enableFilter("myFilter");
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into `Filter` and `FilterDef`, here is [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html)

- At classB side define `FilterDef` with condition
- At classA's relationship, use `Filter` with name referred to filter defined at classB side.

Look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919686/annotation-to-filter-results-of-a-onetomany-association) for example.